# Handle touch in parent view but Handle Click event in child

Tags: android, touch, android-custom-view

i have a custom ViewGroup that extends linearLayout and this view group has a gridView as child . i want if mGridView clicked mGridView.onClickListener called and executed  but handle other touch events(like move mGridView ) in my custom view Group (onTouchEvent() executed ). so i ovveride onInterceptTouchEvent :

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    int action = ev.getAction();
    int y = (int) ev.getY();

    if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && y > mGridView.getTop() )  //y > mGridView,getTop() checks if position of touch in mGridView Position or not.
       return false;

    return true;

}
```

but mGridView.OnClickListener() never called .

Answer (score 1):

A click event is a composite event, it does not consist only of an MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN.

It should have a MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, probably several other MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and finally a MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, and all these inside the bounds of your clicked view.

You should define other MotionEvents to "return false" inside the method onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev).
maybe something like:

```
if( (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWNaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) && y > mGridView.getTop() )
```

Appart from [this](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) which you have probably already read, take a look at [Detecting Common Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

Alternatively(but not really suggesting it) try not using an OnClickListener on your View but an OnTouchListener. With your current code you should receive there the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN you are now returning false

Comment: thank you . what is correct of action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWNaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ?

Comment: for a click to be detected several actions are grouped together
First an ACTION_DOWN then whatever action  inside the bounds of your view except ACTION_CANCEL and then an ACTION_UP.
I think that if you let the ACTION_UP with the ACTION_DOWN, your click will be detected and the OnClickListener will work